# How to disable Security Manager while running JUnit tests in Intellij 2020.1?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I am getting an error like below for few of my JUnit tests running in Intellij 2020.1.

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/ubuntu/build-target/deployment/policies.properties" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:886)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:127)
```

Can someone let me know how can I disable Security Manager in Intellij to get around the error like above?

I have tried setting `-Dtests.security.manager=false` via `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options`. But it is still not working?

Java - OpenJDK 8

Comment: Does this use have got read access at Ubuntu level?

Comment: Yes same work fine if I run it in command line using `mvn test` passing `tests.security.manager` to the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set "-Dtests.security.manager=false" in your Run configuration "VM options".